# How to create kubernetes role for the "deployment" resource?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, k8s-rolebinding, kubernetes-java-client

i am trying to create a namespace role for my kubernetes cluster that will allow my application using the kubernetes sdk to be able to retrieve the deployments via its service account. I am trying to create a role that will give access to the deployments resource as well as create a role binding to apply that role to my service account.

I have gotten this working manually using localstack by simply running this file (kubectl apply -f myFile.yaml) to create the role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: test-deployment-pod-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods", "deployments"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

this successfully creates the role such that the output is:

```
Resources      Verbs
---------      -----
deployments    [get watch list]
pods           [get watch list]
```

however when i connect to my REAL cluster we are on the non-default namespace, lets call it namespace `test`. I am unable to simply apply the file like this due to my restrictions (i guess?) but i know i should be able to create the role since when i run this:

`kubectl auth can-i get deployments -n test`

it responds with `yes`. Attempting to create the role with this command succeeds but the resource is incorrect (deployments.app instead of just deployments, i do see this same behavior when trying to create the role this way using localstack/eks as well):

`kubectl create role my-role --verb=get --verb=list --verb=watch --resource=pods,deployments -n test # succeeds`

`kubectl describe role my-role -n test`

```
Resources        Verbs
---------        -----
deployments.apps [get watch list]
pods             [get watch list]
```

and apparently deployments.apps is NOT enough access to let my `api.listNamespacedDeployment` request succeed from my application.

**Does anyone know how to programatically create the role that has a resource of `deploy` using the `kubectl create role` command? i cannot figure out why it keeps adding `.apps` to the end of `deployments`**

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Deployments have an apiGroup of `apps` (unlike Pods). See e.g. the `apiVersion` attribute in any Deployment manifest.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i dont even see a flag for apiGroups when using kuebctl create role command. its almost like this is only working for me because in my yaml file im using a blank apiGroup. and leaving the apiGroups blank when using the kubectl apply command has actually been working for me (even though im not sure its correct?)

Answer (score 0):

It does seem kubernetes cli was trying to help me out by adding deployments.apps. As some of the comments mention the Deployments kind does belong to the apiGroup of apps. I must have not been giving the correct service account the role or perhaps i was in the wrong namespace. this does appear to work as intended